# Node-SQL with node.js and MS integrated Security

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I have some sample code that is successfully connecting to SQL Server using Microsoft SQL Server user name and password. But I was wondering if there is a way to use integrated security with this script. Basically which means use the logged in user's credentials without supplying a password in the script.

```
var sql = require('mssql');

var config = {
    server: '127.0.0.1', 
    database: 'master',  
    user: 'xx',
    password: 'xxx',

    options : {
        trustedConnection : true
         }
}


var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
    // ... error checks
    if(err) {
    return console.log("Could not connect to sql: ", err);
    }

    // Query

    var request = new sql.Request(connection);
    request.query('select * from dbo.spt_monitor (nolock)', function(err, recordset) {
        // ... error checks

        console.dir(recordset);
    });

    // Stored Procedure


});
```

Comment: Check this answer from Aaron Ballard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40406998/639575

Answer (score 2):

Wish I could add this as a comment but don't have enough reputation yet... but what happens when you run this without providing a username/password in the `config` object?

Windows Authentication happens at the login level so there is no need to provide it at the application level.

Just browsed the documentation and looks like you cannot provide a raw connection string to connect, but to connect you want to build something that looks like this:

`var connectionString= 'Server=MyServer;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes;'`

The source code of the `mssql` module is here: https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql/blob/master/src/msnodesql.coffee... maybe you can fork and do a pull request that would provide an optional flag whether to use Windows Authentication or not, and that flag would remove the `Uid={#{user}};Pwd={#{password}}` (as it's unneeded for Windows Authentication) from the `CONNECTION_STRING_PORT` variable in the module's source code.