# How to connect to SQL Server with windows authentication from Node.JS using mssql module

Tags: sql-server, node.js, npm

Hi I'm unable to connect to SQL server that is using windows authentication in node js. I'm using the mssql module. The error message is :

```
[ConnectionError: Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.]
name: 'ConnectionError',
message: 'Login failed for user \'\'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.',
code: 'ELOGIN' }
```

Here is my code:

```
config = {
    server : "localhost\\MSSQLSERVER",
    database : "mydatabase",
    port : 1433
}

function loadDepts() {
    var conn = new sql.Connection(config);
    var request = sql.Request(conn);

    conn.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    request.query("select deptid, deptname from departments", function(err, table) {
        if (err) {
           console.log(err);
           return;
        }
        else {
           console.log(table);
        }

        conn.close();
        });
    });
}

loadDepts();
```

Comment: where did you put the username?

Comment: I do not put a user name since my SQL Server's authentication method is Windows Authentication. In .Net this is how I would define my connection string: "Server=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=mydatabase". Not sure how to implement something similar to this in Node.js though.

Comment: Oh and I tested it with SQL server authentication, using the sa account, and it works. But what I need is for it to work in Windows authentication.

Answer (score 37):

Since this is a fairly visible answer, I wanted to add in a code snippet that worked for me with Trusted Connection. Got to it from [getglad's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1886901/getglad) edited answer.

```
const sql = require("mssql");
require("msnodesqlv8");
const conn = new sql.Connection({
  database: "db_name",
  server: "server_name",
  driver: "msnodesqlv8",
  options: {
    trustedConnection: true
  }
});
conn.connect().then(() => {
  // ... sproc call, error catching, etc
  // example: https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#request
});
```

Using trusted connection, I was able to execute stored procedures, log the output, and close the connection without any trouble, and [msnodesqlv8](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msnodesqlv8) has been updated more recently than any of the other drivers (latest release was October 2016 as of 11/3/2016), so that seems to be a safe choice as well.

And here's an example using mssql@4.0.4. The only changes are the initial require, which pull in msnodesqlv8 from within mssql, and sql.Connection is now sql.ConnectionPool. You will also need to change your stored procedure calls since the response is different, noted [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#3x-to-4x-changes). Credit to Jon's answer since he updated mine before I did!

```
const sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");
const conn = new sql.ConnectionPool({
  database: "db_name",
  server: "server_name",
  driver: "msnodesqlv8",
  options: {
    trustedConnection: true
  }
});
conn.connect().then(() => {
  // ... sproc call, error catching, etc
  // example: https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#request
});
```

Comment: I realize that this is an older comment but when I try the above code I am getting "Login failed for user ''."  Not sure why it isn't pulling in my windows information.

Comment: @Holt - I have only ever been able to get it to work using an actual connection string. I have added a code example to my answer, if that helps

Comment: Can we use msnodesqlv8 with knexjs?

Comment: @VictorioBerra As stated here our chances to use this with knexjs are pretty slim: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57397602/3647782
Knexjs mssql dialect uses the tedious driver hardcoded and there is no way to simply change it via a config.

Answer (score 33):

I have been struggling too for some time about how to use mssql + Windows Auth, here is how i got it to work on my project.

As pointed out in the [mssql documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#microsoft--contributors-node-v8-driver-for-nodejs-for-sql-server), you need msnodesqlv8 installed too.

```
npm install msnodesqlv8
```

Now, following on [Aaron Ballard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40406998/1269898), you use it like this:

```
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')

const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({
  database: 'database',
  server: 'server',
  driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
  options: {
    trustedConnection: true
  }
})

pool.connect().then(() => {
  //simple query
  pool.request().query('select 1 as number', (err, result) => {
        console.dir(result)
    })
})
```

As a note, i tried to add this as a comment on Aaron's answer, as mine is just a complement/update to his, but i don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: Nice work! Everyone should always use that query when testing connections..... select 1 as number

Comment: I spent so many days trying to get this to work after migrating a system from Node v7 to v18 with multiple IT Ops people getting involved...ALL OF THIS...and the biggest most sincere thank you!!!

Answer (score 27):

I have never been able to get `mssql` + windows auth to work for any of my projects. Try `edge` and `edge-sql` - it has worked for me. [Be sure you install *all* the required packages](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge#scripting-clr-from-nodejs).

https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge

https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge-sql

From there, it's pretty steamlined.

```
var edge = require('edge');
var params = {
  connectionString: "Server=YourServer;Database=YourDB;Integrated Security=True",
  source: "SELECT TOP 20 * FROM SampleData"
};  
var getData = edge.func( 'sql', params);

getData(null, function (error, result) {
   if (error) { console.log(error); return; }
   if (result) {
    console.log(result);
   }
   else {
    console.log("No results");
   }
 });
```

**EDIT**

Well... 10 days after my original answer, apparently `mssql` added Windows Auth to the package. They heard our cries :) [See here](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql/commit/cc1ebe78f00f257e13a06bd8970c04274a27536e#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8R286). I have not tested it yet, but it is officially in my backlog to test integration. I will report back.

FWTW, if `mssql` fits your needs, I would go with it, as 1) `edge-sql` has been dormant for 2 years and 2) the primary contributor has said he has left projects like this "[in the caring hands of Microsoft](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/483)", since he no longer works there.

**EDIT 2**

This keeps getting upvotes and there are comments saying some of the other answers' code examples either aren't working or aren't working on Windows.

This is my code using `mssql`, working on Windows, with `msnodesqlv8` also installed:

```
var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
var config = {
  driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
  connectionString: 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client XX.0};Server={SERVER\\NAME};Database={dbName};Trusted_Connection={yes};',
};

sql.connect(config)
.then(function() {
 ...profit...
})
.catch(function(err) {
  // ... connect error checks
});
```

Comment: I've not had much luck with Windows Auth on [mssql](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql).

Comment: @getglad Please could you give a specific example for the connection string with actual values? I'm a little confused as to whether the {} should be there in practice, I'm getting "TypeError: Invalid server: undefined"

Comment: @ChrisPeacock try replacing `var sql = require('mssql');` with `var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');` - apparently breaking change in https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#3x-to-4x-changes

Comment: Thanks @getglad! That, along with a change to the 'Driver=...' bit fixed it. I didn't realise that the Driver in the connection string referred to an ODBC driver (I didn't realise ODBC even came into it).

Comment: @previousdeveloper did u know now how to get this working in linux

Comment: Works with connectionString. Don't know why it doesn't work when the parameters are supplied separately.

Answer (score 18):

I've tried many variations and this is my complete solution.
I'm using **SQL server Express**.
I'm connecting, in the first instance, to the **MASTER** database only.
You only NEED to change "**YOURINSTANCE\\SQLEXPRESS**".
(Be sure to maintain the double-slash above!!!)
I'm using **INTEGRATED SECURITY** too.
The query relies on nothing at all (in your database).
You need to add your node packages
   ==> **NPM INSTALL MSSQL** and 
   ==> **NPM INSTALL msnodesqlv8** 
Hopefully, your connection issues will be a thing of the past.
Maybe.
Please.

```
// More here -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql
var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
var config = {
  connectionString: 'Driver=SQL Server;Server=YOURINSTANCE\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=true;'
};
sql.connect(config, err => {
  new sql.Request().query('SELECT 1 AS justAnumber', (err, result) => {
    console.log(".:The Good Place:.");
    if(err) { // SQL error, but connection OK.
      console.log("  Shirtballs: "+ err);
    } else { // All is rosey in your garden.
      console.dir(result);
    };
  });
});
sql.on('error', err => { // Connection borked.
  console.log(".:The Bad Place:.");
  console.log("  Fork: "+ err);
});
```

Comment: Was it a " Fork: " error, or a " Shirtballs: " error?

Comment: If it was a "Fork" error, it will be worth double-checking your connection string again.

Comment: its working,, thank , i just need install and add msnodesqlv8

Comment: Thanks @dave, resolved my problem and saved time

Answer (score 5):

For me

I used connection setting as below

```
"server":"",
"domain":"", //sepcify domain of your user 
"port": ,
"user":"", // enter username without domain
"password":"",
"database":""
```

and the TS code

```
import * as sql from 'mssql';

const pool = await new sql.ConnectionPool(connection).connect();
const result = await pool.request()
            .query(`SELECT count(idpart) part_computed FROM demo.PARTs;`);
pool.close();
return Promise.resolve(result.recordset);
```

Answer (score 3):

I could only get a Trusted Connection working using msnodesqlv8 (limited to Windows environments) with a connection string (rather than a config object).

```
const sql = require("msnodesqlv8");

const connectionString = function(databaseName) {
    return "Server=.;Database=" + databaseName + ";Trusted_Connection=Yes;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}";
}

sql.query(connectionString("DatabaseName"), "SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1" , (err, recordset) => {
    if(err) {
        // Do something with the err object.
        return;
    }

    // else
    // Do something with the recordset object.
    return;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using ES6 (ECMAScript), I got it working using the following steps.

1. Download [Microsoft ODBC Driver 18](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) from Microsoft.
2. Install mssql and msnodesqlv8 (`npm install mssql msnodesqlv8`)

Then you can use this driver to connect to the sql server

```js
import sql from 'mssql/msnodesqlv8.js';

// Connect to SQL Server using Windows Auth
const conn = new sql.ConnectionPool({
    connectionString: 'Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes'
});

conn.connect()
    .then(function () {
      console.log("Connected to SQL Server");
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code is  working for me......

```
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')
// config for your database
var config = {
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    server: 'serverNAme\\SQLEXPRESS', 
    database: 'Learn' , 
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me
need to install msnodesqlv8 and mssql. also .......:)

```
    var dbConfig = {
      driver: 'msnodesqlv8',  
      server: "DESKTOP-66LO4I3",
      database: "FutureHealthCareWeb",
      user: "sa",
      password: "pass@123",
      options: {
        trustedConnection: true
    },
    debug: true,
    parseJSON: true
    }; 
    var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

      sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
      if (err) { console.log(JSON.stringify(err)+'..............') }
      else {
        console.log('Connected')
      }
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
const sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");

const conn = new sql.ConnectionPool({
    database: "DB name",
    server: "server name",
    driver: "msnodesqlv8",
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true
    }
});
conn.connect().then((err) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    else console.log("connected");
    
    const req = new sql.Request(conn)
    req.query("select * from table", function(error, res){
        console.log(res)
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to connect with mssql server which run in remote windows server using **windows authentication mode** . Then i found the solution just used like below code.

```
sql.connect("Data Source=172.25.x.x,1433;User Id=CSLx\\Name;Password=xxxxxx1234;Initial Catalog=giveTHedataabseNamel;Integrated Security=True",function(err){ }
```

Comment: are you providing windows password ? we should not provide windows password for window authentication. it should take automatically which user is running the app..

Comment: node mssql module dont have the option to login with windows authentication 
for the sake of the implementation i could find the only above way and for further details refer the git hub issue.

https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql/issues/338

Answer (score 0):

I've just add **domain: "DNAME"**, in config, and as result this config helps me connect  to MS SQL with windows auth.

```
const config = {
            driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
            domain: "DNAME",
            user: 'username',
            password: 'pass',
            server: '7.6.225.22',
            database: 'DBNAME',
            requestTimeout: 3600000, //an hour
            options: {
                trustedConnection: true
            },
            debug: true,
            parseJSON: true
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

This version doesn't need a username or password.

To use windows authentication I installed mssql and msnodesqlv8.

Then in my app.js file:

```
const mssql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
```

Note it is mssql not sql if you're using this example.

```
var config = {
  database:'YOUR DATABASE NAME',  
  server: 'localhost\\SQLEXPRESS',
  driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
  options: {
    trustedConnection: true,
    enableArithAbort: true
  }
};
```

You need to change the database name in config. Other than that it should work. My example:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

        mssql.connect(config, function (err) {
    
            if (err) console.log(err);
            var request = new mssql.Request();
            request.query('select * from dbo.visit', function (err,  result) {
                if(err) console.log(err);
                console.log(result);
            });
    
        });
    
 });
```