# mssql nodejs trustedSecurity

Tags: sql-server, node.js

So I've been trying to connect to my SQL database using a trusted connection (Windows authentication) using **mssql** in **nodejs** but to no luck so far.

I have following config:

```
var express = require('express');
var config = {};

config.mssql = {
    server: 'CLT-GFI-0278',
    database: 'Interview',
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Having this in **config.js** I proceeded to integrate this in the file I want to             use **mssql** in:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sql = require('mssql');

var config = require('./../config');
sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});

router.get('/getYear/:year', function (request, response) {
    sql.Request()
        .query('select * from SomeTable')
        .then(function(recordsets) {
            console.dir(recordsets);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
    response.send();
});

module.exports = router;
```

But when I run the app I get following response:
[image: TrustedConnection not working]

Is there anyone who can guide me in a direction where the trustedConnection would work? I do know that I can create a user and grant it permissions but I would like to get it running like so. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with same problem and read somewhere that

> It's impossible to use Windows Authentication by default.

You have to login with a login/password combination or use `edge` package.

https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge

https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge-sql

Example:

```
var edge = require('edge');
var params = {
    connectionString: "Server=YourServer;Database=YourDB;Integrated Security=True",
    source: "SELECT TOP 20 * FROM SampleData"
};  
var getData = edge.func( 'sql', params);

getData(null, function (error, result) {
    if (error) { console.log(error); return; }
    if (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
    else {
        console.log("No results");
    }
});
```

Comment: I did come across this but isn't edge decommissioned? or no longer being extended as such? I read that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709807/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-from-node-js-using-mssq). The responder says edge has been dormant for over 2 years

Comment: It does indeed seem that mssql still does not work with trustedConnection. I ended up using a user and password for this. Answer accepted but I would not recommend using Edge and go for the username password combination using mssql instead.