# Config entry in node.js in case if of windows authentication to connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, node.js

How to create config entry in Node.Js to connect to SQL Server in the case of Windows Authentication using only `mssql` module?

I'm using this approach:

```
exports.dbConfig = {
    server: "AKASH",
    database: "SampleDB",
    port: 1433,
    options: {
         trustedConnection: true
    }
};
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709807/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-from-node-js-using-mssq

Comment: I don't want to use any other modules like edge and according to my requirement, these solutions are not working for me.

Comment: What library are you using and what version of MSSQL are you using?

Comment: I'm using mssql module & MSSQL 2012.

Comment: You need to use one of the drivers with that library. It uses tedious by default. If this is the case, then the solution in that SO link I posted is valid. You need to update your question with more info if you want more help.