# Node.js Connection with SQL Server windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, node.js, npm, windows-authentication

I'm trying to connect `node.js` to `mssql` in Windows Authentication mode. I installed the `tedious`,`mssql` and `msnodesqlv8` modules, but I still can't figure out how to open a connection.

This is what I tried:

```
    var sql = require('mssql');
    var config = {
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    server: 'POPPY-GI\\SQLEXPRESS',
    database: 'NodinSports',
    options:{
    trustedConnection: true,
    useUTC: true}}

    sql.connect(config).then(function() { 
    new sql.Request().query('select * from users')
    .then(function(recordset){
    console.log(recordset);
    }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);});
    }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);});
```

After running I get a long error saying:

```
    `ConnectionError`: Port for `SQLEXPRESS` not found in 
 `ServerName`;POPPYGI;`InstanceName;SQLEXPRESS;IsClustered`;No;Version;12.0.2000.8;;

    at Connection.tedious.once.err (D:\Never Lazy\University\`AN2, SEM 2\WEB\`Projek`\node_modules\`mssql`\lib\`tedious.js:216:17`)

    at Connection.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at D:\Never Lazy\University\AN2,SEM2\WEB\Projekt\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:570:27
    at D:\Never Lazy\University\AN2,SEM2\WEB\Projekt\node_modules\tedious\lib\instance-lookup.js:91:24
    at Socket.onMessage (D:\Never Lazy\University\AN2,SEM2\WEB\Projekt\node_modules\tedious\lib\sender.js:140:9)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at UDP.onMessage (dgram.js:549:8)
    code: 'EINSTLOOKUP',
```

I would be really thankful for any help.

FIXED:

In `services.msc` check if the followings are enabled:

```
SQL Server(*server_name*) -- in my case `SQLEXPRESS`
SQL Server Browser
SQL Server Agent(*server_name*) -- if you are using `SQLEXPRESS` this doesn't need to run
```

In SQL Server Configuration Manager -> Protocols for *server_name*: enable `TCP/IP`.

To make sure everything will be fine, check the port the server is using (SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Native Client Configuration -> Client Protocols -> *double click on* `TCP/IP` -> Default Port ) , and add the `port: *your_port*` to the code in `var config = { ... }`.

Lastly, change `var sql = require('mssql');` to `var sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");`

Comment: Is POPPYGI a remote server?  Is the SQL Browser service running?  Can you connect using SSMS to this instance?  What port is the service actually using (the SQL Logs will tell you)?

Comment: Local server,  SQL Browser service is running , port is 1433. I don't really understand what do you mean about " connect using SSMS to this instance". 
I added the port:1433 to the 'config' , and now i get an error saying : `ConnectionError: Login failed for user ' '.` [...]

Comment: Thanks for your help, problem solved. ^_^

Comment: If you solved your problem, [you can answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)! This also removes it from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 3):

Install the following modules:

```
"dependencies": {
    "msnodesqlv8": "^0.4.14",
    "mssql": "^4.1.0"
  }
```

My node version: v8.1.4

```
const sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");

const main = async () => {
  const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({
    server: "myservername",
    database: "mydbname",
    options: {
      trustedConnection: true
    }
  });

  await pool.connect();

  const request = new sql.Request(pool);

  const query = `SELECT [FirstName]
    ,[LastName]
    ,[Email]
FROM [Dev].[Users]`;

  const result = await request.query(query);

  console.dir(result);
};
main();
```

(You can do it without async or older versions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40406998/639575)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, msnodesqlv8 only runs on Windows... how to do on other platforms?

Comment: Good job on the packages versions for prev node versions!

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by beatoss works for windows but not for Linux/mac. The msnodesqlv8 driver only works for Windows. For Linux/mac environment, try [odbc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odbc) instead.

Comment: Hey, your answer should be specific to question not in general, you can edit it your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late to answer, but this recently happened to me and drove me crazy!!! I was trying to connect my db to express and working with Windows authentication mode. For two long days, I kept googling and refreshing until I got this article: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/troubleshooting-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-login-failed-user/ 
So in a nutshell; 
First I installed the `msnodesqlv8` driver for Windows authentication, in my server on ssms, I right-clicked on my server then in properties and then security, I enabled SQL server and Windows authentication mode, then in the object explorer, clicked on the plus next to the server, then security, then logins. There I saw `sa` with a cross next to it. In its properties, I changed my password to something easier to remember (optional), then set the login to enable in the status. PHEW! 
Now my config code:

```
    const config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: '123',
    driver: "msnodesqlv8",
    server: 'UZAIR-S_PC\\SQLEXPRESS',
    database: 'LearningExpressJS',
    options: {
        trustedconnection: true,
        enableArithAbort : true, 
        trustServerCertificate: true,
        instancename: 'SQLEXPRESS'
    },
    port: 58018
}
```

This works finally !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: your answer is not about windows authentication. Your answer suggests allowing SQL Server Authentication which is not the same as Windows Authentication.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me