# How to use win-auth in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am able to connect to a SQL Server database using a SQL account. How do I connect to the same SQL Server using windows auth? I have already added `trustedConnection` as `true`.

Note - I am passing the password for the `domain\testetl` account because I am running this from AWS Lambda where I cannot login using that user.

```
'use strict';


const sql = require('mssql');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const config = {
    server: 'ip',
    port: 45,
    user: 'domain\testetl',
    password: 'g',
    database: 'central',
    options: {
    trustedConnection: true
  }
  };

  sql.connect(config, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      callback(err);
    } else {
      const req = new sql.Request();
      req.query('SELECT top 10 * FROM STATS', (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          callback(error);
        } else {
          console.log(result);
          sql.close();
          callback(null, result.recordset);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  sql.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    callback(err);
  });
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to SQL Server with windows authentication from Node.JS using mssql module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709807/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-from-node-js-using-mssq)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to SQL Server with windows authentication from Node.JS using mssql module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709807/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-from-node-js-using-mssq)

Comment: Seems we were thinking the same @alroc. I don't know enough about Node.JS, so I'm not going to vote on this; as it'll automatically lock the question.

Comment: This is not a duplicate because I have already added `trustedConnection` as mentioned in the other question and still get a `Login Failed` error message. @Larnu @alroc

Comment: But, @Aaron ,either of those example has the password in the connection string. Something that is common when using Windows Authentication; as the user is *already* authenticated.

Comment: @Larnu As I mentioned in my question, I have to pass the password because I am running it from AWS where Windows Auth wont work.

Comment: That isn't how trusted connections work though @Aaron . You're trying to mix 2 different authentication methods. I suspect those links do cover what you need. But if you can't authenticate to the AD Controller from the host trying to connect to SQL Server, then you won't be able to use a trusted connection. If you have an AWS Server which can't authenticate to your domain, then a trusted connection is off the cards.

Comment: I have added the `aws-lambda` tag to see if anyone else has any ideas. @Larnu