# Unable to connect to Microsoft SQL Server using Node.js,mssql and express

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am trying to learn Node.js and created a simple project to query the local database. But I get failed to look up an instance error message.

I have checked that the SQL Server services running in services.msc

[image: services.msc picture]

I have verified TCP/IP is enabled

[image: configurations manage pic]

I have tried with the username and password and without it as well. I connect to localdb in SQL Server Management Studio as `(localdb)\v11.0` and below is the screenshot of the properties

[image: image of SQL Server connection properties]

What am I doing incorrectly? What should be actual username and password? What should be the servername?

```
const sql = require('mssql');

// config for your database
const config = {
    user: 'mywindows username',
    password: 'my windows password',
    server: '(localdb)\\v11.0', 
    database: 'test',
    options: {
        encrypt: true
      } 
};
console.log('starting sql');

var connection = new sql.connect(config, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    var request = new sql.Request(connection); 
    request.query('select * from employees', function(err, recordset) {
       if(err)      // ... error checks 
            console.log('Database connection error');

    console.dir("User Data: "+recordset);
    });
});
sql.close();
console.log('ending sql');    
});

app.listen(3002, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3002');})
```

Below is the error message

> { ConnectionError: Failed to lookup instance on (localdb) -
>   getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND (localdb)
>       at Connection.tedious.once.err (C:\Users\vndbsubramaniam\Desktop\React
>   projects\ReactWithSql\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:244:17)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:285:13)
>       at Connection.emit (events.js:197:13)
>       at InstanceLookup.instanceLookup (C:\Users\vndbsubramaniam\Desktop\React
>   projects\ReactWithSql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:945:16)
>       at sender.execute (C:\Users\vndbsubramaniam\Desktop\React projects\ReactWithSql\node_modules\tedious\lib\instance-lookup.js:66:13)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.invokeLookupAll [as callback] (C:\Users\vndbsubramaniam\Desktop\React
>   projects\ReactWithSql\node_modules\tedious\lib\sender.js:43:16)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (dns.js:70:17)   code: 'EINSTLOOKUP',   originalError:    { ConnectionError: Failed to
>   lookup instance on (localdb) - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND (localdb)
>          at ConnectionError (C:\Users\vndbsubramaniam\Desktop\React projects\ReactWithSql\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)
>          at InstanceLookup.instanceLookup (C:\Users\vndbsubramaniam\Desktop\React
>   projects\ReactWithSql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:945:32)
>          at sender.execute (C:\Users\vndbsubramaniam\Desktop\React projects\ReactWithSql\node_modules\tedious\lib\instance-lookup.js:66:13)
>          at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.invokeLookupAll [as callback] (C:\Users\vndbsubramaniam\Desktop\React
>   projects\ReactWithSql\node_modules\tedious\lib\sender.js:43:16)
>          at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (dns.js:70:17)
>        message:
>         'Failed to lookup instance on (localdb) - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND (localdb)',
>        code: 'EINSTLOOKUP' },   name: 'ConnectionError' } Database connection error

Answer (score 6):

After struggling for hours on this one finally found the answer here [SQL to Node connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709807/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-from-node-js-using-mssq)

It seems i have to add msnodesqlv8 package and use add the driver syntax to the config.

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {

const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

// config for your database
const config = {
    database: 'test',
    server: '(localdb)\\v11.0',
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    options : {
        trustedConnection : true
    }
};
console.log('starting sql');

const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
pool.connect().then(() => {
    //simple query
    pool.request().query('select * from employees', (err, result) => {
          if(err) res.send(err)
          else{
              return res.json({
                  data : result.recordset
              })
          }
      })
      sql.close();
})    
console.log('ending sql');
```

});

Answer (score 1):

you will need msnodesqlv8 driver, which you have to paste it in require as

`var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8'),`

as well as you will have to include it in driver section in config object.

```
var config = {
    user:"*****",
    password:"*****",
    database:"*****",
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    server:"*****",
    options: {
        trustedConnection : true
        }
}
```