# How to connect to SQL Server with Windows authentication from Node.JS using knex module

Tags: node.js, sql-server, connection-string, windows-authentication, knex.js

I am trying to connect SQL Server using **knex** with Windows Authentication from my node.js application.

Config:

```
 {
  client: 'mssql',
  connection: {
    database: 'MyDBName',
    host: 'xx.xx.xx.xxx',
    server: 'MY-SERVER_NAME\\SQLEXPRESS',
    options: {
      encrypt: false,
      trustedConnection: true,
    },
  },
}
```

I didn't add username and password in the config as I have added `trustedConnection: true` for **Windows Authentication**.

But I am getting the following error:

> Login failed for user ''.

Even if I add add username and password, I get the same error.

Any suggestion will be of great help. Thanks

Comment: This means the account running the code has no permission to connect. Have you tried connecting to the server using SSMS or [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is?view=sql-server-2017) (which, despite the name, is  the cross-platform database client for SQL Server no matter where it runs)

Comment: I do have the permission. I can access from SQL Server Management Studio using Windows Credential. I think my nodejs application is somehow unable to get the credential

Comment: BTW ADS is based on VS Code, ie on Electron, ie Node.js.

Comment: I have no idea about  Azure Data Studio

Comment: Does the code run under *your* account though, or some other account, eg a service or local account? Does this code run on Windows or Linux?

Comment: It isn't working for any account. It is a windows system

Comment: You can use the link to download ADS. In any case, the error means that the client *did* connect and the server didn't like the account. If `knex` couldn't get the account's token, there would be a different error. You can check SQL Server's error log from SSMS to see what happened, and what the reason was for the failure. BTW is the exact message `Login failed for user ''` or did you remove the account name?

Comment: In the error you can see that Login failed for user ''. It is unable to get the username from my machine

Comment: There was no account name in the error

Comment: Are you running using a local account or a domain account? Local accounts are recognizable only on the machine they are created on. When a local account tries to connect to another computer, eg to a file share or SQL Server, the machine's account is used. Local accounts are almost never used to connect from a client to a remote database.

Comment: Domain Account. We have Windows Authentication in all other applications as well

Comment: Which packages and  versions are you using? Which SQL Server version are you targeting? `knex` uses `mssql` which in turn uses either `tedious` or `msnodesqlv8`. You could use one of the two drivers directly to see whether they can connect or not. It's one of those that's responsible for actually connecting. This way you can isolate the problem and check whether there's a known bug or an updated version

Comment: Looks like `knex` has  a hard dependency on `tedious` which doesn't allow Windows Authentication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`knex` uses `mssql` which in turn uses either `tedious` or `msnodesqlv8`. `tedious` doesn't support Windows Authentication. The default is `tedious`. Trying to use `tedious` with Windows Authentication results in ... `Login failed for user ''.`. The full error message is :

```
(node:16568) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionError: Login failed for user ''.
    at Connection.<anonymous> (K:\testprojects\nodesql\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:244:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:291:20)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at Connection.processLogin7Response (K:\testprojects\nodesql\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1397:14)
    at Connection.message (K:\testprojects\nodesql\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1932:14)
    at Connection.dispatchEvent (K:\testprojects\nodesql\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1084:36)
    at MessageIO.<anonymous> (K:\testprojects\nodesql\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:984:14)
    at MessageIO.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at Message.<anonymous> (K:\testprojects\nodesql\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\message-io.js:32:14)
    at Message.emit (events.js:208:15)
```

Which clearly shows that the source is `tedious`.

To get this I used this snippet :

```
const sql = require("mssql");
const config  = {
  database: "Master",
  server: "myserver",
  options: {
    trustedConnection: true
  }
};


(async () => {
        await sql.connect(config)
        const result = await sql.query`select name from sys.databases`
        console.dir(result)
})()
```

The [docs explain](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#microsoft--contributors-node-v8-driver-for-nodejs-for-sql-server) that you need to use `const sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");` to use `msnodesqlv8`, eg :

```
const sql = require("mssql");
const config  = {
  database: "Master",
  server: "myserver",
  options: {
    trustedConnection: true
  }
};
```

After this change the query runs and produces a list of database names

Unfortunately, this won't help with `knex`, as it [loads and uses](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/lib/dialects/mssql/index.js#L47) `tedious` directly. Despite what the code comment says, [msnodesqlv8](https://github.com/TimelordUK/node-sqlserver-v8) is actively maintained and had a release only 4 days ago.

Comment: Thank you! I have left my laptop in my office... I will try this tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: @AdritaSharma unfortunately this won't work with *knex* because it loads `tedious` [directly](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/lib/dialects/mssql/index.js#L47) The reasoning in the comments no longer holds as `msnodesqlv8` is actively maintained

Comment: Thank You for this detailed explaination. I will try with `msnodesqlv8`

Comment: I used `msnodesqlv8` and I am able to connect. Thanks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your answer! But now I am left wondering, is there a working way to get this working with knex?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect using msnodeqlv8 by making a new dialect based on [this example](https://github.com/knex/knex/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#i-would-like-to-add-support-for-new-dialect-to-knex-is-it-possible)

I just added the msnodesqlv8 module and used the following code, hopefully it helps someone out:

```
require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
let Knex = require("knex");

let Dialect = require(`knex/lib/dialects/mssql/index.js`);
Dialect.prototype._driver = () => require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

let sql = Knex({
  client: Dialect,
  connection: {
    server: "<sql server>",
    port: 1433,
    database: "<database name>",
    driver: "msnodesqlv8",
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true
      }
  }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: i get this error from this code TypeError: Driver.Connection is not a constructor