# Connect to SQL Server with mssql npm package

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, node-modules

I'm trying to write a lambda which will take values from a csv file and insert them to a database in SQL Server. The user account needs to use Windows authentication to connect to the SQL Server to perform the insert.

I found the `mssql` npm module which allows the connectivity, however when I try to run the lambda I get the below error.

> "code": "ELOGIN",
>   "message": "Login failed for user 'domain\\user'.",

This is my code that I'm using with the lambda:

```
"use strict";
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const converter = require("csvtojson");
const zlib = require('zlib');
const sql = require('mssql');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();


const config = {
    user: 'domain\\user',
    password: 'password',
    server: process.env.SQL_SERVER,
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true
    }
};



function unzipS3(keyName, bucketName) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let options = {
            'Bucket': bucketName,
            'Key': keyName
        };

        s3.getObject(options, function (err, res) {
            if (err) return reject(err);

            resolve(zlib.unzipSync(res.Body).toString());
        });
    });
}

function convertToJSON(csvFile) {
    var options = {
        delimiter: ",",
        quote: '"',
        checkType: true,
        output: "json"
    };
    var convertedJson = '';
    return converter(options)
        .fromString(csvFile)
}


exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    var bucketName = process.env.BUCKET_NAME;
    var prefix = process.env.FOLDER_NAME + '/';
    var keyName = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    var csv = await unzipS3(keyName, bucketName);
    var jsonData = await convertToJSON(csv);
    console.log(csv);
    console.log(jsonData);
    var dbconn = await new sql.connect(config);
    dbconn.connect().then(function () {
        console.log('Connection successfull');
        dbconn.close();
    });
};
```

I did some research on the web and some documents were referencing to use in addition to `mssql` module to use [msnodesqlv8](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msnodesqlv8) but it seems like that only works for Windows machines (I'm on a mac). I've tried setting the user name as a variable and formatting that variable so it only has one backslash and using that in the 'user' field but in the CW logs in AWS it still shows the double backslash '\\'.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here to connect to the SQL Server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to SQL Server with windows authentication from Node.JS using mssql module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709807/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-from-node-js-using-mssq)

Comment: Thank @O.Jones for the reference, I did see that link in my research but again it references to the msnodesqlv8 module which I can't load from my macbook.  I guess it is only for Windows machines.

Comment: why not create a username, password to use in your mac, instead of using windows authentication ?

Comment: @ArunK - The lambda will reside in AWS and will run in that environment.  I am doing the development on my machine and that is where I tried to install that npm module (msnodesqlv8) and got the error where the module wouldn't install.

Comment: If you are using serverless framework, I suggest using plugins like `serverless-offline` or `serverless-localstack`, so that you can test using an environment similar to lambda. because if you start to write code targeting mac and linux, you will only find some issues when it runs on lambda. Or else if you are using `vscode`, you can also use `vscode remote` extension to connect to a linux environment and work. thats what I do. good luck