# SQL Server Connection with NodeJS - Certificate is not yet valid

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am new to SQL Server and i am trying to establish connection between Nodejs and SQL Server which is hosted on my Local Machine which is authenticated using Windows Authentication

Here is my Connection Configurations

```
const sql = require("mssql");
require("msnodesqlv8");
const conn = new sql.ConnectionPool({
  database: "ApplicantsData",
  server: "localhost",
  driver: "msnodesqlv8",
  options: {
    trustedConnection: true,
    TrustServerCertificate:true
  }
});
conn.connect().then(() => {
//check
});
```

whenever i try to connect i got an error of

`Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - certificate is not yet valid`

i have searched for this type of error and i ensured that:

1. TCP/IP enabled using SQL Server Configurations
2. Enabled SQL Server Browsing

any solutions/fixes?

Comment: If you are using SSPI to connect to SQL Sever, why are you providing -> TrustServerCertificate:true?

Comment: @RossBush nothing in particular i saw previous answer that included TrustServerCertificate

Comment: You don't need that if you can access the local instance when you log in. Try removing that line and see if you get a better result.

Comment: I tried to remove this line but nothing changes

Comment: Did you allow mixed mode authentication for that sql server instance?

Comment: Also, check out the answer for this question as it may apply.  new sql.Connection instead of ConnectionPoool. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709807/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-from-node-js-using-mssq

Comment: @RossBush i haven't allowed mixed mode authentication i will check it

Comment: Unlike connection string keywords in .NET, Node/Javascript config parameters are case-sensitive. i.e.: `node --eval="console.log(JSON.stringify({FOO:1,foo:2}));"` outputs `{"FOO":1,"foo":2}`. Have you tried using `trustServerCertificate` instead of `TrustServerCertificate`?

Comment: Also, for Windows authentication (which assumes that the Node process is executing in a Windows account context for which there is a Windows Logon configured at the SQL Server), you're probably looking for `options.trustedConnection`, ref: [Microsoft / Contributors Node V8 Driver for Node.js for SQL Server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#microsoft--contributors-node-v8-driver-for-nodejs-for-sql-server).

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with your current date and time of your IoT, where the nodejs is running(assume linux). set the date and time using below command.

```
date MMDDHHMMYYYY
```

For instance,

```
date 062611102023
```

then set the hwclock with

```
hwclock --systohc
```

Run the .js again.