# ConnectionError: Login failed for user '' while window authentication using Nodejs(Nestjs), msnodesqlv8, typeORM

Tags: node.js, sql-server, nestjs, typeorm, azure-data-studio

I have to connect with mssql database using window authentication where I am using Nodejs and msnodesqlv8. I followed [How to connect to SQL Server with windows authentication from Node.JS using mssql module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709807/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-from-node-js-using-mssq) to do the setup code but as it's window authentication so no username/password required but after writing code
connection using above link

```
const sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");
const conn = new sql.ConnectionPool({
  database: "db_name",
  server: "server_name",
  driver: "msnodesqlv8",
  options: {
    trustedConnection: true
  }
});
conn.connect().then(() => {
  // ... sproc call, error catching, etc
  // example: https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#request
});
```

I am getting this error ConnectionError: Login failed for user '', I tried a lot of links to understand the root cause but I am unable to understand also I am working on Mac M1, Azure data studio where manually I am not able to connect to database using window authentication as I am getting error 'Connection failed due to Kerberos error' so is this the cause, please help me to understand the issue.

Comment: Is your computer joined to an Active Directory (or Kerberos) domain?

Comment: Are you sure the credentials like port, host , db name etc. info are correct?

Comment: yes, I changed my machine to window's
const connectionString = "server=W70100\\SQLEXPRESS01.;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}";
sql.query(connectionString, "SELECT * from Emp", (err, rows) => {
    if (err) console.log('Database Connection Failed! godd: ',err);
    console.log(rows);
}); 
error I am getting
[Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]The client cannot connect to the server because the requested instance was not available. Use SQL Server Configuration Manager to make sure the SQL Server instance is configured correctly.