# originalError: ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'userName' when connecting Node.js to SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am trying to connect Node.js to SQL Server for the first time. I would greatly appreciate some help.

This function makes the connection:

```
import config from './dbconfig.js';
import mssql from 'mssql';

export async function getUsers() {
    try {
        let pool = await mssql.connect(config);
        let users = await pool.request().query('SELECT * from users');
        return users.recordsets;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

The config I am importing looks like this:

```
const config = {

    user: 'userName',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'learningProgress',
    options: {
        trustedconnection: true,
        enableArithAbort: true,
        instancename: 'DESKTOP-564IAGD\SQLEXPRESS',
        encrypt: true,
        trustServerCertificate: true,
    }
 
  port:55829

};

export default config;
```

In place of `userName` and `password` I used my Windows user name and password, is that correct?

In place of `instancename` I used `DESKTOP-564IAGD\SQLEXPRESS`, is this correct?

[image]

I will mention that my SQL Server browser is running, and TCP/IP is enabled, IP Addresses - TCP port is set to 1433 (all of them).

This is my error in regards to the userName:

```
    Promise { <pending> }
ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'userName'.
  code: 'ELOGIN',

    isTransient: undefined

  }
}
```

Comment: By default, SQL Server runs on port 1433.

Comment: It won't be your windows username and password, it will be for the SQL server account you are using. There will be a different settings to use the logged in windows user, and you won't need to provide the credentials. Really, check the documentation

Comment: `trustedconnecion` seems to be a spelling mistake.

Comment: Have you tried to use a single authentication mechanism? `trustedConnection: true` is telling it to use the Windows account under which the current Node process is executing - which probably isn't what you expect if this is running under IIS. But you also have `user: 'userName', password: 'password'` telling it to use SQL Logon authentication, which is an entirely different authentication mechanism.

Comment: If I remove userName and password I still get tis error:   originalError: ConnectionError: Login failed for user ''.

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33709807/2422776